# timestamp issue in mysql

Tags: mysql, jdbc

While executing the following query in querybrowser i;m getting correct date.But in jdbc code resultset is returning incorrect date.

```
 pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select DATE(sih.loaded_date) from  tab_ats_sellthroughloader_history sih order by loaded_date desc limit 1");

        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
java.sql.Timestamp saveDate = null;
        while (rs.next()) {

            saveDate = rs.getTimestamp(1);
        }
        System.out.println("result:::::::::::::::::"+saveDate);
```

Comment: Incorrect `date` or format? And you are selecting a `date` but assigning to a `timestamp` in java.

Comment: We can't read in minds. What do you expect this to display, what is your query browser displaying, and what is actually displayed by the above code?